# SQLAlchemy: filter many-to-many joinedload

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have the current table setup for a many to many association between "words" and "phrases":

```
association_table_wp = Table('words_phras', Base.metadata,
                             autoload=True,
                             extend_existing=True)

class Phrase(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'phrases'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    def __init__(self, phrase, explanation=None, active=False):
        self.phrase = phrase
        self.explanation = explanation
        self.active = active

class Word(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'words'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    def __init__(self, word, word_id=None, active=False):
        self.word = word
        self.word_id = word_id
        self.active = active

Word.phrases = relationship(Phrase,
                            secondary=association_table_wp,
                            backref="words")
```

Now normally when I want to look up some words and their phrases I use:

```
words = db_session.query(Word).filter(Word.id.in_(word_ids)).\
             options(joinedload(Word.phrases)).\
             all()
```

This allows me to access `words[i].phrases` to access the phrases associated with a given word.

Now, this works fine, but note that "active" property. I want to filter the words' phrases so that only ones with `active == True` are returned. How can this be done? I have tried several combinations of joins and eager_loading, but none of them have worked as I'd hope.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`contains_eager()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html#routing-explicit-joins-statements-into-eagerly-loaded-collections) is what you're looking for:

```py
words = db_session.query(Word).\
    join(Word.phrases).\
    options(contains_eager(Word.phrases)).\
    filter(Word.id.in_(word_ids)).\
    filter(Phrase.active == True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the options I have tried already, and I waited until today so I could test it just to make sure, but it isn't working. I get the same results as the above query.

Comment: OK, seems like I may have some weird caching issue, but in any case, this does work. Thank you!